# IOs и Firebase, не приходят уведомления. Что делать?

Tags: ios, swift3, push-уведомления, push

Всем привет. Для отправки и получения push уведомлений на ios использую Firebase, пишу на swift 3, токен регистрируется, в настройках проекта загружен сертификат p8, в центре сертификации установлены права, после установки приложение спрашивает разрешения на прием уведомлений. 
Через консоль отправляю уведомления, через какое то время пишет что уведомления разосланы. Но на деле их нет. Не могу понять почему, и что делаю не так?

Comment: Google-Services-Info.plist в проекте присутствует?

Comment: да, все поды и сертификаты тоже есть